# Python-Custom decimal precision printing

Tags: python, printing, format, precision

I want my integer variable to be rounded to 4 decimal places. A number like 3.345679 should be represented as 3.3457.Additionally, the value zero must be represented as 0 and not any other representation.(e.g., -0.0, 0.0, 0.00000). Additionally, I do not want to add extra 0s to floating point numbers. For example, 3.9 should be represented as 3.9, not as 3.9000

Comment: If only for printing you can use f string

a = 0.1234567
print(f"{a:.4f}"

Comment: When you say "represented" you mean *printed*?

Comment: a = 0.12 
print(f"{a:.4f}")  Output: 0.1200 Expected output:0.12 @Calavera

Comment: the number after f represents decimal places for .12 you should use .f2

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to examine the number before you print it. You could write a function for determining how many zeros would appear if you rounded to 4 decimal places:

```py
def getZeroCount(num):
    # this check avoids infinite loop
    if num == 0:
        return 4

    x = num
    tens = 0
    while x % 10 == 0:
        tens += 1
        x /= 10

    return tens
```

Then format the string based on this value:

```py
a = 3.345679
zeros = getZeroCount(a)
stringToPrint = '{:.{w}f}'.format(a, w=4-zeros)
print(stringToPrint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `round()` with a number of decimal places.

```
examples = [
    0,
    3.345679,
    3.9,
    3.0,
    3.00001,
    3
]

decimal_places = 4

for example in examples:
    print(round(example, decimal_places))
```

The code above outputs:

```
0
3.3457
3.9
3.0
3.0
3
```

The only potential problem here is that floating point numbers are printed with at least one symbol after the dot - so there's "3.0" where "3" could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
def custom_decimal(x):
    if x == 0:
        s = '0'
    else:
        s = f'{x:0.4f}'.rstrip('0')
    return s

>>> for x in ( 3.345679, -0.0, 0.0, 0.00000, 3.9):
    print(custom_decimal(x))

3.3457
0
0
0
3.9
```